# How does one position the separate widgets (views) in TeXstudio?

Tags: positioning, texstudio

It does not seem possible to position the widgets -- editor widget, structure widget and PDF viewing widget -- manually according to one's own desire. If it is possible, then how can this be achieved?

The effect I wish to have is that the PDF view is on the left, the editor more or less in the centre and the structure widget on the right.

Comment: this seems not to be featured in TXS and has to be requested from the dev-team.